# Pass values to another page

Tags: php

I have a page where I output some data (page1.php). Also I have another page (page2.php) where I need to pass the values as well.

```
// page1.php

$myVals = '""';

foreach($values as $name) {
    $myVals .= ',"'.( strlen($name) ? htmlspecialchars($name) : ' ').'"';
}

$_SESSION['myVals'] = $myVals;
```

On page2.php I need myVals to be placed into the following string:

```
$xls->addRow(Array("First Name","Last Name","Website","ID"));
```

There are supposed to be separate values for xls file headers. Currently if I put my string in it, it is interpreted as a single value.

```
$xls->addRow(Array($_SESSION['myVals']));
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not store it as an array in page1?

Page1:

```
foreach($values as $name) {
   $_SESSION['myVals'][] = strlen($name) ? htmlspecialchars($name) : ' ';
}
```

Page2:

```
$xls->addRow($_SESSION['myVals']);
```

Comment: Great! I tend to over-think these simple things. Is there a way to add a blank value to the beginning of my array?

Comment: Yup, just do a `$_SESSION['myVals'][] = '';` before the foreach loop.

Comment: Perfect! Just had to add unset($_SESSION['myVals']); before it to avoid incrementing my values ;)

Comment: I am in phase 2 of my project with a new but somewhat similar question. 15 hours later -- no takers :(    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6285132/creating-multidimentional-array-to-pass-values-to-another-page

Answer (score 1):

Note that

```
array("First Name","Last Name","Website","ID")
```

is different from

```
array('"First Name","Last Name","Website","ID"')
```

The first one creates an array with four elements, while the second one creates an array with only one element as the commas are part of the **string** and not of the `array()` statement. Calling `array($_SESSION['myVals'])` is equivalent to the second example, because `$_SESSION['myVals']` is only a **string**.

You should create a proper array:

```
$myVals = array();

foreach($values as $name) {
    $myVals[] = strlen($name) ? htmlspecialchars($name) : ' ';
}

$_SESSION['myVals'] = $myVals;
```

and pass this one to `$xls->addRow()`:

```
$xls->addRow($_SESSION['myVals']);
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain. Yes, it makes perfect sense.